# Как передать данные из компонента в сервис в Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript

У меня есть сервис и компонента, в котором есть переменная  partNumber - сообщает номер раздела в котором я нахожусь и дает 1, 2 или 3

```
export class InfoComponent implements OnInit {
 @Output() partEvent = new EventEmitter();

 public partNumber: number;
 ngOnInit() {
 this.partNumber = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams['part'];
 this.partEvent.emit(this.planetNumber);

   }
}
```

Мой сервис работает с XML и мне нужно использовать в нем переменную `this.partNumber`

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  @Input() planetNumber: string;
  // x2js = new X2JS();
  headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  first = 'assets/first.xml';
  second = 'assets/second.xml';
  third = 'assets/third.xml';

  public x2js = new X2JS();

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  get(): Observable<any> {
      // TODO: pass a URL as a parameter
      return this.http.get(this.first, this.headers).map((res) => res.text());
  }
}
```

Я хочу модифицировать код в нечто подобное

```
      get(): Observable<any> {
        if(this.partNumber === 1){
          return this.http.get(this.first, this.headers).map((res) => res.text());
      } else if(this.partNumber === 2) {
        return this.http.get(this.second, this.headers).map((res) => res.text());
      } else {
        return this.http.get(this.third, this.headers).map((res) => res.text());
      }
}
```

То есть , если я нахожусь в первой части, то сервис будет обрабатывать первый XML, во второй - второй, а третья часть будет для третьего XML.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне передать значение переменной из компонента в сервис?

Comment: Что за _номер раздела в котором я нахожусь_? Типа категории?

Comment: @AGS17 http://localhost:4200/app-book-2?part=1 , это просто адрес компонента

Comment: В них есть хоть что-то похожее? Выглядит так, будто это вообще надо разделить...

Comment: можешь просто внедрить свой сервис в компонент: `constructor(private service: DataService ){...}`, и далее в `OnInit` -> `service.planetNumber = this.partNumber`

Answer (score 1):

В общем по задаче: Вам нужно просто `partNumber` сделать параметром функции в сервисе. Я бы сделал это так:

```
public get(part: number): Observable<any> {
  let url;
  switch(part) { 
    case 1:
      url = this.first;
      break; 
    case 2:
      url = this.second;
      break; 
    case 3:
      url = this.third;
      break; 
    default:
      throw new Error("Bad part number");
  }

  return this.http.get(url, this.headers).map((res) => res.text());
}
```

После протолкните ваш сервис в компонент:

```
constructor(private dataService: DataService ) { }
```

И в компоненте получайте данные:

```
let value = this.dataService.get(this.partNumber);
```

Так же советую избавится от `@Input() planetNumber: string`, т.к. имхо сервисы не должны держать в себе состояния.

Comment: это только если сервис будет вызываться из этого компонента

Comment: @Grundy на то и рассчет